# ZF2: Dependency Injection, MVC, Configurations and Bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a questiom regarding the Zend Framework 2:

I have
library/System and library/Zend. the system is my custom library, which I want to configure de aplication (routes, modules, etc., and redirect user to correct module, controller and/or action).

I don't want to do this inside each application/modules/ModuleName/Module.php file. So, my library/System can do everything related to application configuration.

Comment: Have you tried to access the router directly (Zend\Mvc\Application.getRouter())?

Comment: Return a Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack object without controller/action/params passed by url info.

Comment: @Fge I've tried Zend\Mvc\PhpEnvironment\Request.getRequestUri(), but without success.

Comment: Some more code of your class and what you do might be helpful then

Comment: @Fge It is the problem, I don't do much more then this code, because ZF2 need configuration files in every place, every module, etc. The question is, how can I catch the request, parse, and send to controller, independent of ZF2 Mvc or modular structure.

Comment: You don't need configuration files at all places. Actually you can write a custom module without any configuration object. The only file you must have is the 'Module.php'. All configuration goes by this class - which does usually read the values from files but could pull them off of your custom application class as well.

Comment: @Fge But, it must return a array of configs, which I like to put inside my custom library.

Comment: Register to one of the events then ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As said in the comments above: register to the bootstrap-event and add new routes there:

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Module\Manager,
    Zend\EventManager\StaticEventManager;

class Module
{
    public function init(Manager $moduleManager)
    {
        $events = StaticEventManager::getInstance();
        $events->attach('bootstrap', 'bootstrap', array($this, 'initCustom'), 100);
    }

    public function initCustom($e)
    {
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $r = \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::factory(array(
                'route'    => '/test',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'test'
                )
            )
        );
        $app->getRouter()->addRoute('test',$r);
    }
}
```

`$app = $e->getParam('application');` does return an instance of `Zend\Mvc\Application`. Have a look there to see which additional parts you can get there. The `bootstrap` event is fired before the actual dispatching does happen.

Note that the ZendFramework 1 routes are not always compatible to the ZendFramework 2 ones.

**Update to comments**

```
public function initCustom($e)
{
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    // Init a new router object and add your own routes only
    $app->setRouter($newRouter);
}
```

**Update to new question**

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Module\Manager,
    Zend\EventManager\StaticEventManager;

class Module
{
    public function init(Manager $moduleManager)
    {
        $events = StaticEventManager::getInstance();
        $events->attach('bootstrap', 'bootstrap', array($this, 'initCustom'), 100);
    }

    public function initCustom($e)
    {
        $zendApplication = $e->getParam('application');
        $customApplication = new System\Application();
        $customApplication->initRoutes($zendApplication->getRouter());
        // ... other init stuff of your custom application
    }
}
```

This only happens in **one** zf2 module (named `Application` which can be the only one as well). This doesn't fit your needs? You could:

- extend a custom [module autoloader](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.module.module-autoloader.html)
- extend Zend\Mvc\Application for your own logic
- make your code zf2-compatible

Comment: In this example, my module will be called when "mywebsite.com/test" are requested?

Comment: And if, inside my `library/custom/application.php` I do the same, but here atach the Module instance: `$events->attach('bootstrap', 'bootstrap', array(INSTANCE OF MODULE, 'init'), 100);`, this way, I can auto call the init method and define my module route. (Of course, do this with a little more code.)

Comment: One typo: `public function init(Manager $moduleManager)` and `public function init($e)` with same names.

Comment: Typo fixed. No this won't call your module. This is just an example how to add your routes without config-files. You probably want to add your own routes here instead. On a friendly advice: zf1 and zf2 work almost completly different

Comment: Ok. Every config are made with EventManager? Thanks so far!

Comment: Yes, most of the configuration stuff is done by events (and di)

Comment: Thanks for help-me @Fge! I will go learn more about events =)

Comment: Ok, as I have learned, the `init` method will be executed when I call `Zend\Module\Manager(Registry::get('modules')).loadModules()`. All ok, but, I don't want every module define your route. I want what my custom library automate the process, which is what I've tried for long days without success.

Comment: You want to disable all routes but the ones you define in your module? Besides this is far from good modular & reusable design, you can overwrite the complete router ('$app->setRouter()'). But once again as warning: zf2 is neither compatible to zf1 nor in any final stage.

Comment: I want to define all my routes inside a custom library 'library/custom', and not to have for each module a config method (like init or initCustom) or file like configs/module.config.php. It's not ZF1 relative, I'm  advised.

Comment: Then replace the router in `$app` by a new one with your own routes enabled only (will edit my answer).

Comment: I have learned more about the code, and can't do the basic with this. See my updated question.

Comment: Now I get it! I was thinking that for each module there would be a need for it.